# Does Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider supports tls 1.2 connection with a redis store?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, tls1.2

I am using the Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider nuget package as the session store. We have an azure redis instance which is running currently in tls 1.0. I have added the below setting in the Application_Start() method to enable tls 1.2.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I have bumped the tls version of redis to 1.2. But there is connection error. Is there something else i have to add in the web.config. My current web.config is below.

```
    <sessionState timeout="20" mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <!--<add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000" retrytimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" server="127.0.0.1" ssl="false" throwOnError="true" />-->
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" port="6380" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="" accessKey="" ssl="true" connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000" retrytimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" throwOnError="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that you need to do is add **sslprotocols=tls12** to your Redis connection string.

Example:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" timeout="120" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add type = "Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
         name = "RedisSessionProvider"
         connectionString = "MyRedisConnection"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Note: Be sure that you have Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider version 3.0.2 or later.
Some references:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-remove-tls-10-11

https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/wiki/Configuration

Comment: This is how the connection string look like:<appSettings>
  <add key="MyRedisConnection" value="redis.cache.windows.net:PorNumber,password=RedisKeyOrPassword,ssl=True,sslprotocols=tls12,abortConnect=False" />
</appSettings>